# Change data variable name in netCDF from *empty* to a new name

Tags: python, netcdf4

I have a data which shows that the name of the variable is called *empty*. Therefore, I want to rename it.

```
Dimensions:  (x: 300, y: 183) Coordinates:   * x        (x) float64 4.047 4.14 4.233 4.327 4.42 ... 31.68 31.77 31.87 31.96   * y  (y) float64 71.95 71.86 71.77 71.67 ... 55.24 55.15 55.05 54.96 
Data variables:
*empty* 
Attributes: (12/69)
INPUTPOINTER_FPARCLIM:                  /gpfsm/dnb02/projects/p51/Operati...
INPUTPOINTER_BPLUT:                     /gpfsm/dnb02/projects/p51/Operati...
L4_C_OUTPUT_GRANULE:                    /discover/nobackup/projects/gmao/...
SOC_DOMAIN_CONSISTENCY_DESCRIPTION:     DomainConsistency description is TBD
GPP_DOMAIN_CONSISTENCY_UNITS:           percent (range:1..100)
Source:                                 TBD
                                ...
L4_C_BPLUT_USED:                        /gpfsm/dnb02/projects/p51/Operati...
GPP_COMPLETENESS_OMISSION_VALUE:        0.0
NEE_COMPLETENESS_OMISSION_VALUE:        0.0
RH_DOMAIN_CONSISTENCY_VALUE:            80.86829
nco_openmp_thread_number:               1
NCO:                                    "4.6.0"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does *empty* not mean there are no variable?

Comment: it has values. but the variable has no name

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable with CDO this could probably solved as follows:

```
cdo setname,varname infile outfile
```

Comment: I tried, but got the following:
cdo setname,nee in.nc out.nc



Warning (find_time_vars) : Time variable >record< not found!

cdo setname: Open failed on >out2.nc<
Unsupported file structure
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.10-patch1) thread 0:
  #000: H5D.c line 391 in H5Dclose(): not a dataset
    major: Invalid arguments to routine
    minor: Inappropriate type

Error (cdf_close) : NetCDF: HDF error

Comment: Sorry. In that case you probably cannot solve the problem with CDO